# How to display long content in wp7?

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml, richtextbox

Project target on wp7.5 and above

I use a listbox to display detail information of a post in a forum.

I use a richtextbox to show the body of the post which is mixed by texts and pictures. I create a behavior and bind tje content to the RichTextBox. 
But what tricks me is the RichTextBox can't display all the body. I check online, get to know the reason is the height limitations of the controls which height can not be more than 2048px.

I saw people recommend a article named The Scrollable TextBlock as a solution. But I found no way to implement this.

1 You can't put a ScrollView inside a richtextbox

2 Scrollable TextBlock only supports text, but what I want is a control which can hold both text, image.

3 can bind with text

How to solve the problem?

Comment: Do you have `<RichTextBox ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">` set?

Comment: @ChrisW. I've add it, no use - -

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion you can use the webbrowser control in your application and for the text and images display you can generate the Run time HTML and pass to webbrowser.

you can get an idea to render your text in html form see this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff431811%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks, I will use this as a ItemTemplate of a ListBox, so it means that it will generate lots of WebBrowser controls(15 items per page, and the upcoming page will add just below the original one), will it cause a performance issue?